# Вопрос о работе DHCP протокола

Tags: ip, dhcp

Пытаюсь разобраться в том, как работает `DHCP` протокол.
Если `ip`, который сервер предложил клиенту исказится, то в ответ на `dhcp request ip` сервер вернет `dhcp nack ip`. А что будет если `ip` исказится во время передачи `dhcp ack ip`?

Comment: на выбор клиента. он может послать еще раз запрос с уточнением ip или отказаться от попыток на какое то время и не устанавливать себе адрес (или уйти в 169.x.x.x, как это делает винда)

Comment: Как это исказится?